# Unable to stop increase in page views after refreshing page

Tags: php

I don't actually know what am missing here but I keep on wondering why page view always increases after refreshing the page while I have selected database to see if user IP and Post id exist before inserting new page view into my database.

```
<?php  
    // $post_views & $post_user_id gotten from separate queries

    // get user ip address
    $user_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    // add views
    $new_view = $post_views + 1;

    // select user viewed
    $select_views = "SELECT * FROM users_post_views WHERE for_post_id = ? AND by_user_ip = ?";
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $select_views)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $post_id, $user_ip);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            // fetch results
        }

        if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
            // nothing...
        } else {    
            // insert views
            $insert = "INSERT INTO users_post_views(for_post_id, by_user_ip, for_user_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $insert);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $post_id, $user_ip, $post_user_id);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: ips are not intergers `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $post_id, $user_ip);` so doesnt return anything, but then you insert with string `s`

Comment: I don't really get you.Should I use `s` or `i` to bind IP address @LawrenceCherone

Comment: yes changing to `s` should fix it

Comment: Still facing the same problem @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Have you checked that the IP addresses are stored in the correct format in the DB?

Comment: IP addresses aren't a good way to do this. You could have hundreds of unique visits from the same IP. Also, you have the `user_id` anyway so why not use that exclusively?

Comment: am counting visits from both logged in users and non logged thats why @Steven